# HTTPS Handshake Debugging

Tags: php, http, ssl, https, get

Is there a way to debug a handshake communication in Wireshark, I just need to check if the operation is correct or not, I have integrated TLS in MCU and want to send a GET request to my server, I can see the operation of handeshark in Wireshark, and the encrypted data sent to the server, but on the server side, I don't see any records added to the mysql database.

please see this image:

> [wireshark handshake screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azUag.png)

**for more info please see my second post is kinda related: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522903/implementing-tls-over-http-in-stm32f303rc-using-w5500)*

Log:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2637 33.855902      192.168.1.4           45.84.204.10          TLSv1.2  120    Client Hello

Frame 2637: 120 bytes on wire (960 bits), 120 bytes captured (960 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77), Dst: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.4, Dst: 45.84.204.10
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63991, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 66
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 61
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 57
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 4e3ea400d95c40913a10c5b8394761c17351f121497bab2c…
                GMT Unix Time: Aug  7, 2011 21:41:04.000000000 SE Asia Standard Time
                Random Bytes: d95c40913a10c5b8394761c17351f121497bab2cd902d9c3…
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 6
            Cipher Suites (3 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 10
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=6)
                Type: signature_algorithms (13)
                Length: 6
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 4
                Signature Hash Algorithms (2 algorithms)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 RSA (0x0301)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2682 34.102896      45.84.204.10          192.168.1.4           TLSv1.2  1078   Server Hello

Frame 2682: 1078 bytes on wire (8624 bits), 1078 bytes captured (8624 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66), Dst: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 45.84.204.10, Dst: 192.168.1.4
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 63991, Seq: 1, Ack: 67, Len: 1024
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 81
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
            Handshake Type: Server Hello (2)
            Length: 77
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 609e9998b95481a4551fe5cdf796856b14cdc268405d9ad5…
                GMT Unix Time: May 14, 2021 22:39:04.000000000 SE Asia Standard Time
                Random Bytes: b95481a4551fe5cdf796856b14cdc268405d9ad5444f574e…
            Session ID Length: 32
            Session ID: 417862426c4f746e79dd6e68aedaff40d27d175f688b1a83…
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
            Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 5
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
                Length: 1
                Renegotiation Info extension

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2872 35.805250      45.84.204.10          192.168.1.4           TLSv1.2  252    Certificate, Server Hello Done

Frame 2872: 252 bytes on wire (2016 bits), 252 bytes captured (2016 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66), Dst: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 45.84.204.10, Dst: 192.168.1.4
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 63991, Seq: 5121, Ack: 67, Len: 198
[6 Reassembled TCP Segments (5223 bytes): #2682(938), #2683(1024), #2731(1024), #2732(1024), #2871(1024), #2872(189)]
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 5218
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            Length: 5214
            Certificates Length: 5211
            Certificates (5211 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello Done
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 4
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello Done
            Handshake Type: Server Hello Done (14)
            Length: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   3070 39.245136      192.168.1.4           45.84.204.10          TLSv1.2  321    Client Key Exchange

Frame 3070: 321 bytes on wire (2568 bits), 321 bytes captured (2568 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77), Dst: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.4, Dst: 45.84.204.10
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63991, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 67, Ack: 5319, Len: 267
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 262
        Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
            Handshake Type: Client Key Exchange (16)
            Length: 258
            RSA Encrypted PreMaster Secret

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   3085 39.493438      192.168.1.4           45.84.204.10          TLSv1.2  60     Change Cipher Spec

Frame 3085: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77), Dst: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.4, Dst: 45.84.204.10
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63991, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 334, Ack: 5319, Len: 6
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
        Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 1
        Change Cipher Spec Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   3090 39.559920      192.168.1.4           45.84.204.10          TLSv1.2  99     Encrypted Handshake Message

Frame 3090: 99 bytes on wire (792 bits), 99 bytes captured (792 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77), Dst: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.4, Dst: 45.84.204.10
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63991, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 340, Ack: 5319, Len: 45
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 40
        Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   3099 39.842679      45.84.204.10          192.168.1.4           TLSv1.2  105    Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message

Frame 3099: 105 bytes on wire (840 bits), 105 bytes captured (840 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66), Dst: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 45.84.204.10, Dst: 192.168.1.4
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 63991, Seq: 5319, Ack: 385, Len: 51
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
        Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 1
        Change Cipher Spec Message
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 40
        Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   3122 40.259176      192.168.1.4           45.84.204.10          TLSv1.2  181    Application Data

Frame 3122: 181 bytes on wire (1448 bits), 181 bytes captured (1448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77), Dst: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.4, Dst: 45.84.204.10
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63992, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 127
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http-over-tls
        Content Type: Application Data (23)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 122
        Encrypted Application Data: 0000000000000001a3bc5fda47bb853433419dc3a8e63df6…

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   3147 40.511536      45.84.204.10          192.168.1.4           TLSv1.2  61     Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message)

Frame 3147: 61 bytes on wire (488 bits), 61 bytes captured (488 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{0BF443D1-F659-40FD-96FE-C40B5B821ABA}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_7c:8f:66 (64:2c:ac:7c:8f:66), Dst: IntelCor_7b:8a:77 (2c:6e:85:7b:8a:77)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 45.84.204.10, Dst: 192.168.1.4
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 63992, Seq: 1, Ack: 128, Len: 7
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Unexpected Message (10)
```

Comment: One of the things in my toolbox is this one-liner: `(echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: REPLACE_WITH_DOMAIN\r\n\r\n" ; cat ) | openssl s_client -connect REPLACE_WITH_DOMAIN_OR_IP:443 -servername REPLACE_WITH_DOMAIN`, replace things as needed. If you have a reverse proxy in the front, it is best to use the IP at a certain point, but the domain parts need to be the FQDN.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply .. unfortunately I have no idea what I am supposed to do with this line of code, should I replace the header of the GET request with this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working through my coffee still! If you have access to a Unix/Linux CLI, including the ones from the MS store, you should be able to run this. I know you asked for WireShark, but this in my opinion is a better way to troubleshoot TLS connections in an HTTP context specifically.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to a unix or linux CLI, I'm a Windows 10 guy :(

Comment: I actually am, too, but I keep a Git Bash for Windows installed which comes in handy for situations just like this. Of if you have access to WSL you should be able to run this, too. If I can think of a way to run this using native cmd I'll try to post something. If your domain is the one that starts with `on`, I can tell you that I see a normal Let's Encrypt cert, and I'm connecting using TLS 1.3. I get a redirect from `/trunity?q=hello` to `/trunity/?q=hello` and then I get a bunch of `done` messages, so I think your handshake stuff is all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of the output shows "Application data". Application data are only transmitted if the TLS handshake was successful. Thus any problems you have are outside the TLS handshake.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I have contacted my hosting support and for some reason they did something, after that I am getting a new message after the application data is received, TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message). I will add the handshake log to this post give me 1 moment please

Comment: handshake log is added to the post please take a look at this

Comment: @AustynWilson: As I said, the TLS handshake completed successfully. What you present now is a problem outside the TLS handshake (and thus outside what you ask about in the title). Everything known about this problem is basically "something went wrong". It is impossible to debug this based on the presented information. More information might be available on the server side, for example in some log files.